# Sync two div using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

In my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YxcS8/4/) , you can see two parent div and child div in each parent !
The child div from First parent div can drag and resize ( Using [JQueryUI](https://jqueryui.com/) ).
  I have `dragEnd` and `resizeEnd` event for this div .

What I want to do is , after `dragEnd` , to set the location of child div of Second Parent div , same as first's child div .
And also , after `resizeEnd` ,  to set the size of child div of Second Parent div , same as first's child div .
Want to synchronize two child div.
Thanks !

**html**

```
   <div id="resizable" class="ui-widget-content">
    This is text Line 1<br/>

  </div>
    <img src="http://www.psdgraphics.com/file/abstract-background.jpg" width="400" height="150"  />
</div>

    <br/>
Second<br/>
    <div id="previewContainer">
  <div id="previewText" class="ui-widget-content2">
    This is text Line 1<br/>   
  </div>
    <img src="http://www.psdgraphics.com/file/abstract-background.jpg" width="400" height="150"  />
    </div>
<br/>
```

**JavaScript**

```
   var DEF_HEIGHT = 100; // the #resizable default height
$( "#resizable" ).resizable({
    containment: 'parent',handles: "se",stop:resizeStop,

  aspectRatio: true,
  resize: function( event, ui ) {        
    var curHeight = (ui.size.height/ DEF_HEIGHT) * 100;

    $(this).css('font-size', curHeight + '%');
  }
}).draggable({containment: 'parent'

             });

 $( "#resizable" ).draggable({
start: function() {

},
drag: function() {

},
stop: function() {
alert("Drag End");  
}
});

$("#resizable").resizable({
    stop: function(event, ui) {
    alert('Resize End');
    }
});

function dragStop(event, ui){
}

function resizeStop(event, ui){ 
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
$("#resizable").resizable({
    ...
    stop: function (event, ui) {
        $preview.css({width: this.style.width, height: this.style.height});
    }
})
.draggable({
    ...
    stop: function (e, ui) {
        $preview.css($(this).position());
    }
});
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/YxcS8/6/